# How to dynamically add <a> tags given an index of HTML page's string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making a search function for my website. So far, I've found the string the user searches for in the whole website, and I'm able to print the string and the context of the string. I have achieved this by using `$.get` on my HTML pages, then stripping the HTML to leave the pure text I want to search in. I then find the index of the string I'm looking for, then use `substr` to find the context of the input string (a few indexes ahead and behind).

Now, I need to link to the original page when a user clicks on a search result. My research says to use `<a>` tags, but how do I dynamically insert those into the HTML page with the index I have? And the index I have isn't even the complete page; it's stripped of tags.

These are the relevant parts of my code:

JavaScript:

```
function getIndicesOf(searchStr, str) { //get the indices of searchStr inside of str
    var searchStrLen = searchStr.length;
    if (searchStrLen == 0) {
        return [];
    }
    var startIndex = 0, index, indices = [];
    str = str.toLowerCase();
    searchStr = searchStr.toLowerCase();
    while ((index = str.indexOf(searchStr, startIndex)) > -1) {
        indices.push(index);
        startIndex = index + searchStrLen;
    }
    return indices;
}

function search() {

    obj=document.getElementById("searchButton");
    obj.onclick = function() {

        var searchInput = document.getElementById('searchBox').value;

        var allPageContent = ['chap/telem.php', 'chap/nestor.php', 'chap/aeolus.php', 'chap/calypso.php', 'chap/circe.php', 'chap/cyclops.php', 'chap/eumaeus.php', 'chap/hades.php','chap/ithaca.php', 'chap/lestry.php', 'chap/lotus.php', 'chap/nausicaa.php', 'chap/oxen.php', 'chap/penelope.php', 'chap/proteus.php', 'chap/scylla.php', 'chap/sirens.php', 'chap/wrocks.php']; //contains all text

        var allText = '';

        for (var i = 0; i < allPageContent.length; i++){
            $.get(allPageContent[i], function(data){

                var div = document.createElement("div");
                div.innerHTML = data;
                //allText = div.textContent || div.innerText || ""; //gets the text to search in, stripped of html
                alltext = data;
                allText = allText.replace(/(\r\n\t|\n|\r\t)/gm," ");
                console.log(data);

                var indices = getIndicesOf(searchInput, allText); //the variable indices is the array that contains the indices of the searched text in the main text

                indices.forEach(findContext);
            })
        }

        localStorage.output = '';

        function findContext(currentValue, index) {

            if (currentValue <= 16) {
                searchContext = "..." + allText.substr(currentValue, 100) + "...";
            } else {
                searchContext = "..." + allText.substr(currentValue-15, 100) + "...";
            }

            localStorage.output = localStorage.output + searchContext + "<br /><br />";
        }
        console.log(localStorage.output);
    };

};
```

HTML:

```
<script>document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = localStorage.output;</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit confusing what you're trying to achieve, considering your HTML, but replying to this

> My research says to use `<a>` tags, but how do I dynamically insert
>   those into the HTML page with the index I have?

this would do the trick

```
var output = document.getElementById("output");

var a = document.createElement("a");
var linkText = document.createTextNode("my linked text");
a.appendChild(linkText);
a.href = "http://example.com";

output.appendChild(a);
```

Comment: I see that this would work to append an <a> tag to something given its id. But the problem I'm having is that I want to append an <a> tag into a web page. I used $.get to make a string out of the whole web page, so I know the index of the string at which I want to put the <a> tag. I'm sorry if I'm not being clear, but I think you got the gist of my question with your answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Andy do you know the structure of such webpages? In your `data` if you seem to have said structure. Just add the `a` tag to `data` on the correct point.